# Html helper to show display name attribute without label

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have this:

```
[Display(Name = "Empresa")]
public string Company{ get; set; }
```

In my aspx I have:

```
<th><%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company)%></th>
```

And this generates:

```
<th><label for="Company">Empresa</label></th>
```

Are there any html helper extensions to only show the display attribute without label, only plain text?  My desired output is this:

```
<th>Empresa</th>
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I tried DisplayFor or DisplayTextFor as suggested, but they are not valid because they generate:

```
<th>Amazon</th>
```

They return the value of the property... I want the name from the Display attribute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Late Edit**

In >= MVC4, just use `@Html.DisplayNameFor`

**Before that**

use your own Helper

```
public static MvcHtmlString SimpleLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
) {
  var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
  string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
  string resolvedLabelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedLabelText)) 
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

  return MvcHtmlString.Create(resolvedLabelText);

}
```

Comment: DisplayFor and DisplayTextFor return the valur of name... i want the value of the display attribute

Comment: `DisplayNameFor` would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @DanielSchilling I don't mind your downvote, just can kindly remind you that that extension method did not exist at that time... Now if you check all posts on MVC1, 2, 3, I'm sure you'll find many things to correct ;)

Comment: :(  My apologies.  I did not sufficiently check this out - I made too many assumptions.

Comment: But what if want my helper method work also with only `this HtmlHelper` and not `this HtmlHelper<TModel>` ? The use case - I want to use this helper for grid column headers and the view model points to parent, not to the model of the records in the grid.